# std::sort ( from <algorithm> ) crashes

Tags: c++, linux, stl, stl-algorithm

The following program, a simple vector sorting one, crashes for t >= 17 at the second sort invocation. First sort succeeds even for t == 100.
Struggled for quite some time but I'm not able to figure out what is wrong. Can someone please help me?

I've tried it on a MacBook Air as well as a linux machine and, surprisingly, I am seeing the same result.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

    using namespace std;
    struct tc
    {
        unsigned int n;
    };
    bool sort_by_n( tc a, tc b )
    {
        return a.n <= b.n;
    }
    vector<tc> tcv(100);
    vector<int> tv(100);
    int main()
    {
        unsigned int t;
        cin >> t;
        for ( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < t ; i++ )
        {
            cin >> tcv[i].n;
            tv[i] = tcv[i].n;
        }
        sort( tv.begin(), tv.begin()+t); // ## This one works even for t == 100.
        sort( tcv.begin(), tcv.begin()+t, sort_by_n ); // ## This one crashes for t >= 17
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to provide a **strict** weak ordering, but

```
bool sort_by_n( tc a, tc b )
{
    return a.n <= b.n;
}
```

is only a weak order. A strict weak order **must** return `false` if the elements are the same. You need to change it to:

```
bool sort_by_n( tc a, tc b )
{
    return a.n < b.n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. That worked. I'm surprised that it results in this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @vrk001 The sort algorithm is probably going into an endless recursion until it used up the available stack space and it then crashes.

Comment: Oh I see. So, probably, for sort sizes <= 16, there's one kind of handling that doesn't crash and for sizes >= 17, it's this one that's less forgiving! Thank you for helping me out! :-)

Comment: @vrk001 I don't think it's just the size that matters, you could probably construct cases that are smaller than that which will crash and some cases larger than 17 might still work. It's not really predictable as it depends on the initial order of the elements and, of course, on the implemented algorithm which is not exactly specified.

Comment: You're right. It's not only the size. Earlier, I was testing  with all equal elements for sorting. That's when I was seeing crashes only for t >=17. But, now, after you pointed out, I tested with all distinct elements and I see that it's not crashing at all.

Comment: @vrk001: It's quite common to see such a difference in behavior. The normal sort is recursive, but like all recursive algorithms there's a lower limit at which recursion stops. Your compiler vendor probably benchmarked using a non-recursive algorithm for the last 32/16/8/4/2 elements, and found out that stopping recursion at 16 elements was best. Other vendors, benchmarking different implementations on different CPU's will probably find different values.