# Rcpp std::sort malfunction on Mac OS 12.5

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, rcpp, clang++, std

The following code with Rcpp caused segmentation error on my MacOS but works fine on my Linux OS. After ruling out possibilities, the `sort` function called in the cpp code caused the problem on Mac OS. From the language-level, I don't see any issue with the code.

find_nn_corr.cpp

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;


/*
    Find ordered nearest neighbors based on a correlation Matrix. 
    Assuming the absolute value of the correlation is monotonically 
    decreasing with distance.
    Returns an n X (m + 1) matrix similar to `GpGp::find_ordered_nn`.
*/
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix find_nn_corr(const NumericMatrix &corrMat, int m){
    int n = corrMat.rows();
    IntegerMatrix NN(n, m + 1);
    NN.fill(NA_INTEGER);
    NN(0, 0) = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        int *order = new int[i + 1];
        iota(order, order + i + 1, 0);
        sort(order, order + i + 1, [&corrMat, &i](int &j, int &k){
            return corrMat(j, i)>=corrMat(k, i); });
        for(int j = 0; j < min(m + 1, i + 1); j++)
            NN(i, j) = order[j];
        delete[] order;
    }
    return NN;
}
```

test.R

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("find_nn_corr.cpp")
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
some_matrix <- matrix(runif(n * n), n , n)
cov_mat <- some_matrix %*% t(some_matrix)
sd_vec <- sqrt(diag(cov_mat))
corr_mat <- t(t(some_matrix / sd_vec) / sd_vec)
m <- 10
NNarray <- find_nn_corr(cov_mat, m)
```

My solution is to re-define and to use my own `sort` function. Since the problem is kind of fundamental, I would like to raise it here to see if more experienced programmers can see where the issue is.

Comment: In cases like this, the problem is almost always in the comparison function.  Does your comparison function implement "strict weak ordering" on the data?  Specifically, (1) iis `f(a, a)` always false?  _I suspect not_

Comment: Possible dups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483971/program-crash-in-stdsort-sometimes-cant-reproduce, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757210/stdsort-from-algorithm-crashes

Comment: For starters, which `sort()` do you think you are calling? With the namespaces flattened (bad idea in general) it could be `std::sort()` or `Rcpp::sort()`.  Same with `min()`

Comment: And when I remove the two namespace flatteners, use explicit `Rcpp::` and `std::` and put your example code into the C++ file with the `/*** R` trick to have it called,  then `R -d valgrind -e 'Rcpp::sourceCpp(pathtofile)'` has no issues with the code.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, valid suggestion on namespace, thanks! But the cause for the segmentation fault was "strict weak ordering" as mentioned in @Marshall Clow. After replacing `corrMat(j, i)>=corrMat(k, i)` to `corrMat(j, i)>corrMat(k, i)`, the issue was fixed.

Comment: Gotcha.  You should not even need a comparison lambda on 'plain old data'.